# How to retrieve Geode server statistics for a Geode client proxy region?

Tags: proxy, geode

I am trying to get centralized region statistics from a server region using the client region shortcut PROXY.

From the looks of things, it appears that the statistics are all coming from the client (last modified updated on a put call and local region creation, etc.).

This does not work for my use case, as I do not perform any updates to the region in my process, but still need access to the information (updates occurring in another process/client).

- Is there any way to do this?
- Am I correct in assuming the events updating the last modified for the region are local events only (i.e. not propogated from the server)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to access MBeans on the server to get server side statistics. This thread answers what you want: [Accessing a remote MBean server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270173/accessing-a-remote-mbean-server)